# OpenCL: Values of __local array are lost after a barrier call

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I have a kernel storing some partial results in a local array before reducing
them into a single value (see the example below). Before the reduction process
starts, a barrier is placed to ensure all threads have successfully written their
partial data. However, the barrier resets the values of the temporary array to 
default values (i.e. 0.0f for floats).

Minimal example:

```
__kernel void simulate_plate(__local float *partial)
{
    __private int lpos;

    lpos = get_local_id(0) + get_local_id(1) * get_local_size(1);

    partial[lpos] = 1;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    // At this point partial[i] == 0 for all i

    // reduce data...
}
```

The argument `partial` has the following initializer:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, local_group_size * sizeof(float), NULL);
```

The clSetKernelArg() call returns a status code `CL_SUCCESS` and the kernel
terminates without any errors.

Another observation is that swapping lines `partial[lpos] = 1` and 
`barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)` achieves the wanted result --- all components of
the array `partial` now equal to 1.

Any input why this behaviour occurs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the index should be like this

lpos = get_local_id(0) + get_local_id(1) * get_local_size(0);